# how to change the scope for recursive asyncio functions

Tags: scope, python-asyncio, global

I have **two async functions** with local scope and **one checking function** with global scope. The **two async functions** reference each other (hence recursive behaviour).

All three functions are called from the main async function.

So the setup looks like this:

```py
import asyncio


# globals
x = 0


async def main():
    ''' this is the main function '''
    print('hello from main function')
    print('local x:', x)
    
    asyncio.ensure_future(what_is_x())
    await first_async(x)
    print('got here', x)
    


async def first_async(x):
    ''' this is a function '''
    print('hello from first function')
    x = x + 1
    print('local x:', x)

    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await second_async(x)
    


async def second_async(x):
    print('hello from second function')
    x = x + 1
    print('local x:', x)

    if x > 5:
        print('exit second function...')
        return
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await first_async(x)


async def what_is_x():
    ''' this is a function '''
    while True:
        print('what is x ?', x)
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    syncio.run(main())
```

The result (of the above) is this:

```
hello from main function
local x: 0
hello from first function
local x: 1
what is x ? 0
hello from second function
local x: 2
what is x ? 0
hello from first function
local x: 3
what is x ? 0
hello from second function
local x: 4
hello from first function
local x: 5
what is x ? 0
hello from second function
local x: 6
exit second function...
got here 0
```

I try to avoid usage of the `global` keyword (supposedly best practice).

So my question is, what is the best way to ensure x is consistent throughout ?

And also, can i make `what_is_x()` block the other two async functions in the current setup ?

Answer (score 0):

`x` in yours `first_async` and `second_async` functions is a normal, local variable, and changes in it are only withn the scope of each function. Each time a line with `x = x + 1` is executed, the local variable changes its reference to a new int object.

THere is nothing "obscure" on this code. If you'd try to make `x` global in all three functions (by using the "global" statement, instead of passin g it as a parameter), it would be equaly easy to have code that would go into an infinite loop, and still have nothing of obscure going on.

The way it is, though, global x is never changed from its initial value.

If you really think you need everyone to sync using a global value, just do it - change your `first_async` and `second_async` functions to read:

```
async def first_async():
    global x
    ...
```

instead.  Also, there are context_vars that can handle the scope of variables per task, instead of globally: you'd also do not want to pass "x" as a parameter - but maybe it is more useful to whatever is your intent there - https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html